# Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character '\\' looking for beginning of object key string

Tags: json, powershell, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a valid json string in powershell script to send to as a parameter to a command but I keep getting an error

> Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character '\' looking for beginning of object key string

This is how I tried it:

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p "{\"imagePullSecrets\": [{\"name\": $nameToPatch}]}" -n $namespaceToPatch
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to escape the `"` character like this `\"` however in PowerShell you can use backtick character `` ` `` to escape

e.g.

```
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p "{`"imagePullSecrets`": [{`"name`": $nameToPatch}]}" -n $namespaceToPatch
```

Comment: The error is now changed to "Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character 'i' looking for beginning of object key string"

Comment: This string should be good now, maybe there is something wrong with your command? Perhaps you should add something like `--type='json'` ? The json seems to be incorrect in any case if you run it through (online) json validator